# How are "all types of beings originally formless"?

Tags: death, name-and-form

How are "all types of beings originally formless"?

- p100 The Sutra of Hui-neng, Grand Master of Zen: With Hui-neng's
  Commentary on the Diamond Sutra

I'm asking because [this](https://www.lamayeshe.com/article/death-intermediate-state-and-rebirth) page [quoting His Highness the Dalai Lama] says

> Immediately thereupon, the intermediate state begins—except for those
>   reborn in the formless realms of infinite space, infinite
>   consciousness, "nothingness" or peak of cyclic existence, for whom the
>   new life begins immediately upon death

If we all are originally formless, then our original nature has no intermediate state, while our unenlightened state does.

How can that be?

Comment: I'm unable to understand the question. How can an original state have an intermediate state? How can an unenlightened state not have an intermediate state?

Answer (score 1):

The pull downwards into form, into the unenlightened craving for identity, is driven by craving. Craving leads to grasping and then to rebirth.

> [SN12.23:4.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.23/en/sujato#sn12.23:4.6): I say that rebirth has a vital condition.
>
> [SN12.23:4.7](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.23/en/sujato#sn12.23:4.7): And what is it?
>
> [SN12.23:4.8](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.23/en/sujato#sn12.23:4.8): You should say: ‘Continued existence.’
>
> [SN12.23:4.9](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.23/en/sujato#sn12.23:4.9): I say that continued existence has a vital condition.
>
> [SN12.23:4.10](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.23/en/sujato#sn12.23:4.10): And what is it?
>
> [SN12.23:4.11](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.23/en/sujato#sn12.23:4.11): You should say: ‘Grasping.’

In contrast, moving upwards skillfully, we have practice that leads to the formless and beyond:

> [SN46.54:15.9](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.54/en/sujato#sn46.54:15.9): The apex of the heart’s release by equanimity is the dimension of nothingness, I say, for a mendicant who has not penetrated to a higher freedom.”